# Recreate iPhoto library package from contents

Tags: macos, photos.app

Yesterday I needed to copy an iPhoto library through the CLI. I forgot a slash and accidentally copied the contents of the library package instead of the whole package.

Is there anyway to recreate the library package from the contents? The copy operation took 22 hours, so would be really great if I didn't have to start  the file copy all over again.

Comment: This probably would be easier to answer if you could add the commands you've used and a directory listing of the copied "library".

Comment: Okay, this was on someone else's computer. I'll try to get these. Basically the contents are the same as what you see when you right click an iphoto library and then hit 'show package contents'

Answer (score 1):

It might be a simple extension problem:

Try adding .photoslibrary to the Photos Library folder name - basically try turning the folder into a type Photos will accept.

Interestingly, after having done something similar myself, after recovering my data from Backblaze, adding the extension switched the folder to a 'library' icon, but did not auto-hide the extension itself.
Applying similar logic to a folder by adding .app to its name auto-magically changes it into an 'app' [non-functioning] & hides the extension.

You can fix this, if you see a similar result, by getting info on the Photos Library.photoslibrary file & checking 'Hide extension'

[image]